# Umoja.Models.Subject at lambda_method(Closure , CreateDto , Subject , ResolutionContext )

Tags: c#, api, automapper

Please help, I wish to understand this situation am facing. Am creating a new Subject and every thing looks clear to me, I have other models with the same code and they work find except this
**Object that am sending**

```
    {
      "title": "a",
      "summary": "b",
      "teacher": "c",
      "date": "d",
      "churchId": 1
    }
```

**My Model**

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ChurchId { get; set; }
}
```

**Dto**

```
public class CreateDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ChurchId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult <ReadDto> CreateSubject(CreateDto CreateDto)
    {
        var subjectModel = _mapper.Map<Subject>(CreateDto);
        _subjectRepository.CreateSubject(subjectModel);
        _subjectRepository.SaveChanges();

        var ReadDto = _mapper.Map<ReadDto>(subjectModel);
        return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetSubjectById), new {Id = ReadDto.Id}, ReadDto);
    }
```

**subjectProfile**

```
    public Subject()
    {
        CreateMap<Subject,ReadDto>();
        CreateMap<CreateDto,Subject>();
        CreateMap<UpdateDto, Subject>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not carefull my SubjectProfile class, I wrote **Subject** instead of **SubjectProfile**